# Android Gallery, Images way to the right

Tags: android, xml, android-xml, android-gallery

I'm trying to make a gallery using this code http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html i'm trying to make 3 across and 6 down but the other images past the first row are way off the screen to the right. Any advice to get the other images under the first row.

Code:

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/message_zoom_touch_expand" />

    <!-- This is an example layout containing thumbnail image buttons that, when pressed,
         zoom in to show more detail. All of the zooming and animation logic is in
         the ZoomActivity class. -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!-- These buttons don't have any decorations (3D bevel, etc.), but it's still
             important to show feedback on touch or focus. The custom
             "ToughHighlightImageButton" ImageButton subclass helps achieve this by drawing
             the standard system "pressed" and "focused" overlay upon user interaction. -->

        <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumb_button_1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_1" />

        <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumb_button_2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_2" />
  <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumb_button_3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_2" />

                            <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
                   <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumb_button_4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_2" />
                   <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumb_button_5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_2" />
                   <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumb_button_5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_2" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- This initially-hidden ImageView will hold the expanded/zoomed version of the
     images above. Without transformations applied, it takes up the entire screen.
     To achieve the "zoom" animation, this view's bounds are animated from the
     bounds of the thumbnail buttons above, to its final laid-out bounds. The implementation
     of this animation is in the ZoomActivity class. -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/expanded_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description_zoom_touch_close" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your horizontal LinearLayouts are nested where they should be siblings:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/message_zoom_touch_expand" />

    <!-- This is an example layout containing thumbnail image buttons that, when pressed,
         zoom in to show more detail. All of the zooming and animation logic is in
         the ZoomActivity class. -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!-- These buttons don't have any decorations (3D bevel, etc.), but it's still
             important to show feedback on touch or focus. The custom
             "ToughHighlightImageButton" ImageButton subclass helps achieve this by drawing
             the standard system "pressed" and "focused" overlay upon user interaction. -->

        <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumb_button_1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_1" />

        <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumb_button_2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_2" />
  <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumb_button_3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_2" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
                   <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumb_button_4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_2" />
                   <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumb_button_5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_2" />
                   <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumb_button_5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- This initially-hidden ImageView will hold the expanded/zoomed version of the
     images above. Without transformations applied, it takes up the entire screen.
     To achieve the "zoom" animation, this view's bounds are animated from the
     bounds of the thumbnail buttons above, to its final laid-out bounds. The implementation
     of this animation is in the ZoomActivity class. -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/expanded_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description_zoom_touch_close" />

</FrameLayout>
```

You could also consider using a [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) instead.

Comment: I have changed it but still looks the same. The code looks the same to me. Sorry for being a noob :S

Comment: Oh It changed now but now crashes